# Getting original data from kendo UI DataSource

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

In the Kendo UI documentation for the `DataSource` component, it states that the `data` function is used to get data items for the data source.

However it also states that if the data source is bound to a JavaScript array (via the data option) the `data` method will return the items of that array. Every item from the array is wrapped in a `kendo.data.ObservableObject` or `kendo.data.Model`.

How can I retrieve the original unwrapped data items (i.e. having same reference) that were passed into the data source?

I ask because I'm using a Kendo UI treeview control and in its event handlers (e.g. check event) I want to update the original data item for a tree node based on some custom logic.

**Update**

For example here is a simple treeview having a single node (of course in a realistic scenario the tree would  contain many nodes) . When checking the node I want to get a reference to the original data item for the checked node. `this.dataItem(e.node)` does not return the original data item as the log statement outputs false.

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
  var mydata =  [
    { text: "foo", checked: false}
  ];
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  checkboxes: true,
  dataSource: mydata,
  check: function(e) {    
    console.log(this.dataItem(e.node) == mydata[0]); //I want this to output true
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can get to the records independently by referencing your data source and using the `.at(x)` function, where `x` equals whatever record of your data source you are attempting to access. So to get the first.

```
var theData = yourDataSource.at(0);
```

To update it, you then use `.set` and `.sync`.

```
theData.set('userFirstName', 'Joe');
theData.set('userAverageTime', 10);
yourDataSource.sync();
```

Using `.set()` is handy because if you store all your updates into an iterable collection, then you can just run through them.

```
$.each(updatedVars, function(key, element) {
   theData.set(key, element);
});
yourDataSource.sync();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately the at() call does not return the original data item, it returns a data item wrapped in an ObservableObject.I want it to return the original data item so that I could potentially update it without having to lookup the item in the array that was passed into the datasource.  I've updated my question to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way get the underlying object behind the `kendo.data.ObservableObject` directly.

However, you can still rely on the dataSource to find out what was the index of your original item.  You can do that by calling `dataSource.data().indexOf()` but you have to keep in mind that the index mapping is only possible if your original array indexes still match the ones you have provided to the dataSource:

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
    var mydata =  [
        { text: "foo", checked: false}
    ];
    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        checkboxes: true,
        dataSource: mydata,
        check: function(e) {

            let checkDataItem = this.dataItem(e.node);
            let checkIndex = this.dataSource.data().indexOf(checkDataItem);
            let underlyingData = mydata[checkIndex];

            if (underlyingData == mydata[0]) {
                alert("same instance");
            } else {
                alert("different instance");
            }

        }
    });
</script>
```